# Is it possible to host local server for proccesing python code?

Tags: android, python, cloud, local

I want to host my python code locally so that I can use it in a mobile application. Basically, I have an opencv project and I want to use it in a mobile application.   Is it possible to call this python function from my mobile and process it on local cloud and send the result back to the mobile?
If yes, what technologies can I use?

Comment: Since you are using android can't you use GRPC?. https://grpc.io/

Comment: The issue with this question is there are way too many options for solving this problem. A typical solution would be to create a rest server that runs your opencv code. Another approach would be an [rpc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) approach. If you state what cloud you are using that may be helpful.  [GRPC](https://grpc.io/) is a good approach for android apps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.   I've checked the mentioned ways, GRPC seems good. But still, I can't figure it out, How the client and server communicate.  In all the tutorials available,  client and server are on the same system.